# ksh rename multiple files with prefix entered by user to another prefix entered by user

Tags: rename, ksh, prefix

pretty new to scripting...

Lets say I have multiple files with multiple prefixes in current directory. I need to rename them based on user input.
Let's say I have aaa_file.dat and bbb_file.dat aaa_log.dat ccc.txt and so on.

Script will ask to enter "old prefix" and enter "new prefix" and search files with "old" prefix and mv it into name with "new" prefix.

```
print "enter old prefix" ;

read old ;

print "enter new prefix" ;

read new ;
```

find and rename part is where I get stuck..

```
for $old in * ;
do mv $old_* $new_* ;
done
```

If I enter as user aaa and the zzz my files, my result should be:
aaa_file.dat and aaa_log.dat are now named zzz_file.dat zzz_log.dat

Comment: You need to spend a little time reading `man mv` and making small test cases. Also, trun your code thru http://shellcheck.net . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes in

```
for $old in * ;
do 
   mv $old_* $new_* ;
done
```

When you use a for-loop, a value will be assigned to the loop variable. So drop the `$` in `for $old in *`.
You already have assigned a value to the variable `old`, you do not want to overwrite it with a new value. Use a new variable like `for file in *` (or `for file in ${old}*`).
Variables can have understores in their name. `$old_*` is not the same as `${old}_*`. Get used to using those braces in all cases except for one character variables when they are followed by a space or quote.
You are hoping for some magic, when you write `${new}_*`. The variable will be extended to its value (like zzz), the shell searches for files starting with `zzz_` (non found) and will try (when you hae written `mv ${old}_* ${new}_*`) to move all files with their name starting with aaa_ to a directory called `zzz_*`.
So construct a new filename from the old one with something like `sed`:

The new filename must be constructed from the old filename.

```
for file in ${old}_*; do
   newfile=$(echo "${file}"| sed "s/^${old}_/${new}_/")
   # Remove the word echo when the command shows the mv commands you like
   echo mv "${file}" "${newfile}"
done
```